# Why does this javascript work...but this doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I load everything on my page.
At the end, I have this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">loadNewVideo('u1zgFlCw8Aw',0)</script>
```

It doesn't work.
But if I substitute it with this, it works.:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="loadNewVideo('u1zgFlCw8Aw',0);" >
```

In the .JS file, this is the function:

```
function loadNewVideo(id, startSeconds) {
            alert('In-the-function');
          if (ytplayer) {
            alert('Found-ytplayer');
            ytplayer.loadVideoById(id, parseInt(startSeconds));
          }
        }
```

Apparently, "ytplayer" is false in the first one!??

Comment: You should show the complete code. Where does ytplayer come from?

Comment: Where is ytplayer defined and what is it?

Comment: If you can give us a link then we could look in Firebug, or you could...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have an answer, but perhaps this will help you figure out when the **ytplayer** component is ready for use:

```
var startTimer = new Date().getTime();
function ytplayerReadyCheck() {
  var ready = !!ytplayer;
  if (!ready) {
    window.setTimeout(ytplayerReadyCheck,50);
  }
  else {
    var endTimer = new Date().getTime();
    alert('ytplayer is now ready!\n\nWe waited '+(endTimer-startTimer)+' milliseconds for it');
    loadNewVideo('u1zgFlCw8Aw', 0);
  }
}
ytplayerReadyCheck();
```

Of course, this is scarcely replacement for figuring out where **ytplayer** is defined in the first place! Perhaps it's defined in a .js file that's dynamically loaded **after** the document has loaded?

I'd highly recommend getting hold of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) so you can more easily debug this kind of thing.

Comment: Correct. It takes some time before ytplayer loads. Therefore, I put a setTimeout before calling that loadNewVideo function! and then it works.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what `ytplayer` is, but I imagine this problem has something to do with the DOM not being fully loaded. Have you tried this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadNewVideo('u1zgFlCw8Aw', 0);
});
</script>
```

**edit**: If this doesn't work, you will have to give us more information. As Tim and Peter asked you in comments to your question, can you tell us where `ytplayer` is defined and what it is? I'm assuming it stands for YouTube Player, maybe it's being loaded/defined *after* you were calling `loadNewVideo`?

For example, if the code snippet above is above the part where `ytplayer` is defined in your document, this would still be called before `ytplayer` is loaded, depending on how you're loading it. As I said, please supply some more information.

Comment: Indeed you are correct; javascript runs as soon as it's read, so you need to make sure anything you want is declared about the script you're running, or (better still) do everything in the 'load' event (as you demonstrate) :)

Answer (score 4):

I would say this is because the DOM hasn't totally loaded at that stage.  You want to hook the body onLoad event, or use jQuery to get the $(document).ready() hook.